# show session expired message for longer time before redirecting to login page

Tags: session, liferay

All,

in my liferay portlet when the session expires, the page gets redirected to login page.

Before redirecting to login page we are showing the message saying `Session expired, redirecting to login page`. Problem is that the message just flashes before the login page appears. I want to show this message say for some 3 sec before redirecting to login page. Is there any portal-ext property to specify this. My current contents of portal-ext.properties file is

```
session.timeout.warning=1
session.timeout.auto.extend=false
session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true
```

help..

Answer (score 0):

`session.timeout.warning` indicates the **duration of the countdown warning**.

For eg., if it is set to 1, it means User will be warned for 1 minute.

Below configuration in `web.xml` indicates that if User remains idle for 30 minutes without doing any activity, his Session will be destroyed.

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

For more details on this behaviour, please read [this bug in session warning interpretation](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/745187)  post.

As a side note there is a nice [Jquery plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-dialog.htm) for your requirement.

If you want Session to be destroyed after 30 mins but at 29th minute you want to Warn the User, then your code will look like below,

```
$j.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    idleAfter: 10440,   // 29mins
        ..
        ..
```

Now as you know your session will expire after 30 mins. So, after 30th min, your session will expire and return to your configured page.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and you can take help of following JQuery plugin which provides this feature with customization at different levels. You can configure these customization when the plugin is initialized, like one below.

```
....    
force: 300000,   
....
```

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Session-Timeout-Alert-Plugin-With-jQuery-userTimeout.html

Demo: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Session-Timeout-Alert-Plugin-With-jQuery-userTimeout/